# How to make height stay 100% even on resize?

Tags: css, height

I have a div with a height of 100%, but when I view responsive layouts and I scroll down, the background color of the 100% high div stops right after I scroll. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/serok/MzZt4/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make div 100% height of browser window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The % measurement of height is based on the page height. The scroll is because your content doesn't fit into a block with height 100%. But why do you want to set the height to 100%? Try `height: auto;`

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/MzZt4/1/

If you want to ensure that your div wouldn't be shorter that your page, you can try adding: `min-height: 100%`.

Comment: It was the min-height I was looking for, thanks! :-)

Or then again, since it and height:auto do the same thing, what is the difference?